# Bloquear visualização e edição do arquivo RPT do Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Eu tenho uma aplicação em C# e criei alguns relatórios que ficam na pasta da aplicação, o problema é que se alguém copiar os arquivos do relatório (.rpt) o mesmo se tiver o Crystal Reports instalado vai conseguir visualizar e alterar as configurações do arquivo.

Como faço para impedir isso? Tem como compilar ou criptografar o arquivo?

Obs.: Eu não quero compilar os relatório junto com o exe da aplicação pois isso torna o exe muito grande.

Comment: Se você não quer compilar eles juntos com a aplicação e não quer mandar os arquivos soltos, o que resta?

Comment: Não sei, colocar uma senha no .rpt?